# Tablesorter with unknown # of columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I am working with tablesorter and am building a header with the following code:

```
 table.push(['<div class="first"></div>', '<div class="model">Model</div>', 
             '<div class="third" style="width: ' + ColumnWidth[3] + 'px;">' + ColumnNo[3] + '</div>',
            '<div class="fourth" style="width: ' + ColumnWidth[4] + 'px;">' + ColumnNo[4] + ColumnUnit[4] + '</div>', 
            '<div class="fifth" style="width: ' + ColumnWidth[5] + 'px;">' + ColumnNo[5] + ColumnUnit[5] + '</div>',
            '<div class="sixth" style="width: ' + ColumnWidth[6] + 'px;">' + ColumnNo[6] + ColumnUnit[6] + '</div>', 
            '<div class="seventh" style="width: ' + ColumnWidth[7] + 'px;">' + ColumnNo[7] + ColumnUnit[7] + '</div>',
            '<div class="eighth" style="width: ' + ColumnWidth[8] + 'px;">' + ColumnNo[8] + ColumnUnit[8] + '</div>', 
            '<div class="ninth" style="width: ' + ColumnWidth[9] + 'px;">' + ColumnNo[9] + ColumnUnit[9] + '</div>',
            '<div class="tenth" style="width: ' + ColumnWidth[10] + 'px;">' + ColumnNo[10] + ColumnUnit[10] + '</div>', 
            '<div class="eleventh" style="width: ' + ColumnWidth[11] + 'px;">' + ColumnNo[11] + ColumnUnit[11] + '</div>',
            '<div class="twelfth" style="width: ' + ColumnWidth[12] + 'px;">' + ColumnNo[12] + ColumnUnit[12] + '</div>', 
            '<div class="thirteenth" style="width: ' + ColumnWidth[13] + 'px;">' + ColumnNo[13] + ColumnUnit[13] + '</div>',
            '<div class="fourteenth "style="width: ' + ColumnWidth[14] + 'px;">' + ColumnNo[14] + ColumnUnit[14] + '</div>', 
            '<div class="fifteenth" style="width: ' + ColumnWidth[15] + 'px;">' + ColumnNo[15] + ColumnUnit[15] + '</div>',
            '<div class="sixteenth" style="width: ' + ColumnWidth[16] + 'px;">' + ColumnNo[16] + ColumnUnit[16] + '</div>', 
            '<div class="seventeenth" style="width: ' + ColumnWidth[17] + 'px;">' + ColumnNo[17] + ColumnUnit[17] + '</div>']);
```

This works like a charm, however, I have no way of knowing how many columns will be needed ahead of time, so I need to build the array 'table' dynamically.

Here is what I have come up with for that:

```
var tableHeaderVar = [];

tableHeaderVar.push(['<div class="first"></div>']);
tableHeaderVar.push(['<div class="model">Model</div>']);

if (ColumnWidth[3] != 0) {
   tableHeaderVar.push(['<div class="third" style="width: ' + ColumnWidth[3] + 'px;">' + ColumnNo[3] + '</div>']);
           };

if (ColumnWidth[4] != 0) {
   tableHeaderVar.push(['<div class="fourth" style="width: ' + ColumnWidth[4] + 'px;">' + ColumnNo[4] + ColumnUnit[4] + '</div>']);
           };
.
.
.
table.push([tableHeaderVar]);
```

Basically, this checks the set width, which will be 0 if no column is selected. Then, checks the widths for each column to decide whether the column gets included in the array. This code will build the header vertically down the left side of the table, rather than across the top. I captured the output for both methods and used Beyond Compare to compare them. They are compared as "Binary Same", which should mean they are absolutely identical.

First I tried using individual table.push statements, but the results were about the same. I thought maybe the header (and table data) needed to be pushed as a group, so I decided to use one array variable (tableHeaderVar) to build the HTML and then push it all to table at once. Unfortunately, something seems to be not quite right with my method.

Would anyone happen to know something that might work?

**Edit**
There appears to be no resulting HTML for the datatable in either the working (static # of columns) or non-working (# of columns set on the fly) versions. Here is the HTML placeholder for the table (it is identical in both):

```
<div id="data-grid" class="datagrid">
<div id="testtable"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see, it's empty. Here is my tablesorter declaration:

```
$('#testtable').tablesorter({
  theme: 'default',
  widthFixed: false,
  widgets: ['stickyHeaders'],
  widgetOptions: {
  build_source: table,
    build_headers: {
    rows: 1,
    classes: [],
    text: []
    },
    build_footers: {
      rows: 0
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: The requirements you set are confusing. Is the `tableHeaderVar` being added for each row? So basically you want to use `<th>`'s instead of `<div>`'s? Also, tablesorter won't work on tables that don't have a `<thead>` with a header row to click on, so how do you expect this table to sort? Can you share an example of what your resulting table will look like.

Comment: Sorry if my post was confusing. The table is already functioning as it should, including sorting. I do not necessarily want to use <th>. I want to find a way that I can add the number of columns the user specifies, instead of a fixed number of columns like I have now. I don't really want anything else to change, because, as I said, it's working fine now, except for the fixed number of columns.

Comment: What I'm saying is that it only seems to build the header appropriately when I .push it all at once directly to the array that tablesorter pulls from (the array called table). If I try to build it a column at a time based on the number of columns the user has selected. it doesn't work. Also, if I build it a column at a time using a second array, and then pass it all at once to the array that tablesorter pulls from, it doesn't work then either. The variable tableHeaderVar is used to build each column. If the user has selected 10 columns then there would be 10 values passed into tableHeaderVar.

Comment: The code above is code I worked with you on, @Mottie when originally building this table.  It was under another question I asked awhile back. I used an example you gave and modified it to work for my scenario. I use the build table widget and specify the first row as the header, and it works fine without a <thead>

Comment: Well, I've managed to get the header working by changing:  

table.push([tableHeaderVar]);

to:

table = tableHeaderVar + ',';

But, the data rows are now appended as part of the header, meaning it's basically one long header with the header values and then the data all included as columns.

Comment: Can you provide a demo.

Comment: There are a lot of moving pieces that go along with this table, but I will try to get a fiddle together.

Comment: You can just post the resulting HTML, it'll make it more clear on how the pieces fit together.

Comment: Original question has been edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have found the answer. The main issue was that when using the tablesorter build table widget, passing an array (in this case used to add the required columns one at a time) into another array (used as the datasource for the build table widget) simply won't work correctly. After comparing the results of the two arrays, I didn't find any differences, but there was something there that was throwing it off. Also, the datasource array cannot be built one value at a time. At least, I didn't have any luck with that.

Here is what I had to do:

```
var tableHeaderVar = [];

tableHeaderVar.push(['<th><div class="first"></div></th>']);
tableHeaderVar.push(['<th><div class="model">Model</div></th>']);

if (ColumnNo[3] != null) {
  tableHeaderVar.push(['<th><div class="third" style="width: ' + ColumnWidth[3] + 'px;">' + ColumnNo[3] + '</div></th>']);
};

if (ColumnNo[4] != null) {
  tableHeaderVar.push(['<th><div class="fourth" style="width: ' + ColumnWidth[4] + 'px;">' + ColumnNo[4] + ColumnUnit[4] + '</div></th>']);
};
.
.
.
table = '<thead>' + tableHeaderVar + '</thead>';
```

So, as you can see, I built an array dynamically to include each column that was needed using the `<th>` tag. Then, after all the columns were selected, I passed that array into a string variable and enclosed it with the `thead` tag.

I did something very similar with the table body, except used the `<td>` tag. As I looped through each datarow, I enclosed each with the `<tr>` tag. These tags didn't appear to be needed when using an array as the datasource, but when using a string value, they were crucial.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, but it might not be the answer you are looking for.

There are already tools out there for sorting tables so if you get sick of making your own.

[Here](http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Demo) is one for example.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm already using tablesorter. The arrays in question are the data source for the tablesorter plugin.

Comment: You are using both jquery.tablesorter.js and tables.js? Any css like `table.tablsorter thead {cursor:pointer}` ?

Comment: Not tables.js, only tablesorter. Most of my css is in an external .css file.

Comment: One possible (and inefficient) answer would be to recreate the first code example for each possible number of columns, but that doesn't seem like a desirable approach.

Comment: Why are you using Div's btw? and not `tablesort table`? with `<td> / <tr>` tags?>

Comment: It's for column alignment. The entire table is built dynamically. In addition, the header and table data are built seperately. Using <td> and <tr> tags causes the header and data not to line up correctly. I believe it was Mottie, who maintains quite a bit of the tablesorter code, who had that suggestion for alignment. It has worked extremely well.